# How to increase the intellisense font in PyScripter?

Tags: font-size, pyscripter

How do I  increase the intellisense font in PyScripter?
When I type the dot(.) the dropdown I get as suggestions has very small font. I want to increase that for better visibility.

Tried the IDE options but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you specify the IDE options you tried and what specifically you changed?

Comment: I right-clicked on the editor, selected Editor options. In the popup window, under Display-> Editor Font, I clicked on Font and increased the Font size.